# Profile Permissions overriding dashboard folder permissions

Tags: permissions, profile, sharing, permission-sets, dashboard

I have a requirement to restrict access for a user for a dashboard folder. On basis of that, I have given only view access to that user under our dashboard folder

Now, when I log in as that user, I could able to edit the dashboard. When I checked the user's profile, I could see that the user has following access

> Manage Dashboards in Public Folders

Now, is this the expected behaviour that profile permissions dominate dashboard folder sharing settings or am i missing anything here. Please suggest?

Comment: Everything you do is to increase access not to decrease what is already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In salesforce you cannot restrict access of what is already given by some other access policy. For ex., if profile grants you edit access to an object, you cannot grant permset with just read access and expect user would  have just read access.

In this case, profile is granting broad access and hence that wins.